# Why does pthread_create() return 12?

Tags: c, pthreads

For some reason, `pthread_create` isn't allowing me to pass a `struct` as an argument. The issue is not system related, although I have not had a chance to test it on anyone else's box. It simply won't allow me to pass a `struct` for some reason; it returns error #12.

The issue is not with memory. I know 12 is ENOMEM, and "that should be that", but it's not.. it simply won't accept my struct as a pointer.

```
struct mystruct info;    
info.website = website;
info.file = file;
info.type = type;
info.timez = timez;
for(threadid = 0; threadid < thread_c; threadid++)
   {
    // printf("Creating #%ld..\n", threadid);
    retcode = pthread_create(&threads[threadid], NULL, getstuff, (void *) &info);
   //void * getstuff(void *threadid);
```

When I ran this code in GDB, for some reason, it didn't return code 12.. but when I run it from the command line, it returns 12.

Any ideas?

Comment: The argument to the thread routine `getstuff()` is the pointer to `&info`, which is not a thread ID, despite your comment that its argument is a 'threadid'.  You're probably aware of this, but just double checking.

Comment: Suppose you pass a null pointer instead of the address of `info`; you could make `info` into a global variable since the threads all use the same information - just don't modify it in any of the threads.  Do you still run into memory problems?  Have you memory mapped any files or shared memory segments anywhere?  Are you working on a 32-bit or 64-bit platform (compilation)?  Have you tried to create some thread attributes for the second argument to `pthread_create()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error code 12 on Linux:

```
#define ENOMEM          12      /* Out of memory */
```

You are likely running out of memory. Make sure you're not allocating too many threads, and be sure to `pthread_join` threads when they're done (or use `pthread_detach`). Make sure you're not exhausting your memory through other means as well.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a stack object as a parameter to pthread_create is a pretty bad idea, I'd allocate it on the heap. Error 12 is ENOMEM.

Comment: I tried allocating it using malloc but it still returned 12; after applying correct changes for using a pointer, it still had the same affect.. its like it only accepts typecasted long ptrs

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some proper error handling.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static void fail(const char *what, int code)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", what, strerror(code));
    abort();
}

...
if (retcode)
    fail("pthread_create", retcode);
```

On my system, 12 is `ENOMEM` (out of memory).